# Cannot use relu activation in IndyLSTMCell in TensorFlow 1.10

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, relu

I tried the IndyLSTMCell in TensorFlow 1.10. It works with the default activation (tanh), but it does not work with nn_ops.relu. When I set the activation to relu, the loss became NAN. IndyGRUCell has the same problem.

The relu activation does work with IndRNNCell, however, when I stacked it to 4 or 6 layers, I did not see any improvement of the model capacity.

The cell was placed inside tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell to get multiple layers, then tf.nn.dynamic_rnn. I tried seq2seq model (Google's NMT model) based on the new cell type as well.

The experiments were performed on both GPU version and CPU version of the new TensorFlow (1.10.0) with Python 3.6.

Any suggestion to fix/address this issue would be very appreciated. Thanks.